# how to include angular translator in better way.?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

In one of my project im using "https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate"

for static text translation in Client side.

in Controller i have code like this:

```
$scope.myName = serverValue.name;
```

in html view i have code like this :

```
<p>{{myName|translate}}</p>
```

And  also i saw below code section can be used to translate the run time values.

```
<p translate="{{myName}}"></p>
```

Here my question is **"Which is best and Why ?** "

Note :  "Before down voting please leave your comments"

Answer (score 2):

substantial edit on my previous statement.

Using the directive reduces the number of watch statements setup, and will overall provide better performance.

Source http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive

So use

```
<p translate="{{myName}}"></p>
```

Comment: The angular-translate filter is synchronous. 
and The directive is asynchronous.   is these two  factors did you considered before saying better options?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with EDDIEC for the point of view.

But Directive works fine for static data and it  wont react for dynamic data .

Filter will keep watch on the input param and it will trigger as soon as it changes.

So i feel "Filter" is the best

Comment: This is due to bug in angular-translate (see #701 there)