# Angularjs translate in nested tag

Tags: angularjs

Good day,

I'm trying to translate using the directive way this portion of html

```
<h1>First text to translate<small>Second text to translate</small></h1>
```

But I encounter some difficulties. For example if I try:

```
<h1 translate>KEY<small>Second text to translate</small></h1>
```

the key will not be translated and I see it on the page and if I try:

```
<h1 translate="KEY"><small>Second text to translate</small></h1>
```

this time the key is translated but the second text disappear.

To make it work I must use the translate service inside the controller or remove the nesting. Any advice?

Comment: Indeed very good explanation refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540877/correct-use-for-angular-translate-in-controllers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it as a filter instead of directive:

```
<h1>{{'KEY' | translate}}<small>{{'Second text to translate' | translate}}</small></h1>
```

See https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.filter:translate