# How to get translation ID from function in HTML using with angular-translate

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-translate

I have an `ng-repeat` placing some images with a caption from an array:

```
<span ng-repeat="foo in bar">                   
   <p ng-click="myFunction(foo)" ng-init="imgsrc=foo.image">                                                    
      <img ng-src="{{imgsrc}}" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand"/>
      <br />
      <span >My Caption</span>                                                                                  
   </p>     
</span>
```

This works perfectly, but now I want to change the caption of each image based on the current language. I have `angular-translate` working like this:

```
<div translate>MY_TRANSLATION_ID</div>
```

But now I need to get the translations ID from my `foo` object in the loop. I tried:

- `<span translate>{{foo.translationID}}</span>`
- `<span translate>foo.translationID</span>`
- Creating a function that will return the translation ID:
  `<span ng-init="text=myTranslate(foo)">{{text}}</span>`

But nothing works. Is this possible? I'm trying to avoid saving the translated string in my `foo` object directly because I'm using async loading and I'm changing the language dynamically so it's not that easy or I couldn't get it working properly (also as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22378981/1335209) I should be doing my translations in my HTML code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`translate`](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Getting-Started#using-translate-filter) filter:

```
<span>{{ foo.translationID | translate }}</span>
```