# Show only one value in ng-show if same data is coming for the condition

Tags: angularjs

Show, it display the result as per language. Suppose english is there in myAngApp1.value it will display english. But in SharePoint list all the four languages english value so it is displaying result 4 times. 
My requirement is if  myAngApp1.value is equal to english then it should not display 4 times english.

```
              <span ng-show = "(customer.GLAcctLongTextEN).indexOf(myAngApp1.value)!=-1"> 
                {{customer.GLAcctLongTextEN}}
             </span>
              <span ng-show = "(customer.GLAcctLongTextPT).indexOf(myAngApp1.value)!=-1">    
                {{customer.GLAcctLongTextPT}}
             </span>

              <span ng-show = "(customer.GLAcctLongTextES).indexOf(myAngApp1.value)!=-1">    
                {{customer.GLAcctLongTextES}}
             </span>
              <span ng-show = "(customer.GLAcctLongTextZH).indexOf(myAngApp1.value)!=-1">    
                {{customer.GLAcctLongTextZH}}
             </span>
              <span ng-show = "(customer.GCoAGLcode).indexOf(myAngApp1.value)!=-1">  
                {{customer.GLAcctLongTextEN}}
             </span>
             <span ng-show = "(customer.Title).indexOf(myAngApp1.value)!=-1" >    
                {{customer.GLAcctLongTextEN}}
             </span>
         </td>
```

Comment: Try to use [angular-translate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540877/correct-use-for-angular-translate-in-controllers).

Comment: @Mistalis is right, no point in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-switch. below is the sample code.

```
<p ng-switch="status">
    <span ng-switch-when="wrong">
       Wrong
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
       Correct
    </span>
</p>
```