# $translate.instant('id); not updating when the language changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have an angular app where two languages are used. I used $translate.instant('id'); in my controller to bind some variables. But when I change the translation language using $translate.use('jp'); The controller variables wont change.

I used 'translate' filter in my HTML. That one will change but controller variables wont change. Is there any way to implement it?

Initialized using the below code.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: '/translations/',
  suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
$translateProvider
  .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
```

In a controller I used the below code.
    vm.userName = $translate.instant('USER_NAME');

When the language change using the below code

```
$translate.use('jp');
```

The username doesn't change.

Comment: Do you have a sample code so that we can have a closer look?

Comment: Edited. Please check now.

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your language file is not fully loaded by the time you are calling `$translate.instant('USER_NAME')`

It is also **not recommended** to do the translations on your controller because a translation is just a representation (view) and it should not be dealt in your controller logic.

If you simply want to translate the `userName` you can do this (assuming you have already done it):

`<p>{{USER_NAME | translate}}</p>`

A closer look at this problem is mentioned in the following SO question:

[Correct use for angular-translate in controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540877/correct-use-for-angular-translate-in-controllers)

Check @PascalPrecht (the author of angular-translate) @RobinvanBaalen's answers